# Objective c how to reset AVCaptureDevice exposure to defaults

Tags: objective-c, avcapturesession, iso, avcapturedevice, exposure

I'm setting custom exposure/iso with the camera using:

```
AVCaptureDevice* cd = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[cd setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:cmtime ISO:iso completionHandler:nil];
```

This works fine.  However, for the duration of the app's session these custom settings persist.  Is there a way to reset the capture device's exposure/iso settings?  I've tried something like:

```
if([captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error]){
    [captureDevice setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:captureDevice.activeFormat.minExposureDuration ISO:captureDevice.activeFormat.minISO completionHandler:nil];
    [captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

But this doesn't reset the camera to the default settings.

Comment: It looks like the only way to restore the defaults is to kill the app.  Apple dropped the ball on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can store exposure mode before customising it

```
AVCaptureDevice* cd = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

self.defaultExposureMode = cd.exposureMode; // store in some property

if([cd lockForConfiguration:&error]){
    [cd setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:cmtime ISO:iso completionHandler:nil];
    [cd unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

and then restore it when needed

```
AVCaptureDevice* cd = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([cd lockForConfiguration:&error]){
    cd.exposureMode = self.defaultExposureMode;
    [cd unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: That's a possibility.  I was hoping there was a way to tell the camera to "resume as you were".

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to work.  I record the current ISO and exposure before ever calling setExposureModeCustomWithDuration.  Since these values are auto adjusting, it can be caught at the "wrong" time.  Either too much exposure or too little.

Comment: @user3335999, then reset to some constant, eg. `.autoExpose`